# How to let the right float menu to scroll when overflow?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to let the right float menu to scroll when overflow, but failed, here is the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/xuwtqmj3/ .

```css
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.menu-left {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='menu'>
    <span>Menu</span>
    <div class="menu-left">
      <span>111</span>
      <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>tttttt</li>
      </ul>

      ...... more

      <span>66</span>
      <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>tttttt</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <pre>
    asdfasdf
    asdf

    ...... more

    sfd
    </pre>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried to add `display: inline-block` but not work, have tried to wrap the `ul` inside a `span` and not work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `height` property to .menu class.
Eg i have added `height:100vh;`

```css
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    float: right;
    right: 0;
    height:100vh;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    overflow: auto;
}
.menu-left {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class='menu'>
<span>Menu</span>
<div class="menu-left">
<span>111</span>
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>tttttt</li>
</ul>

<span>22</span>
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>tttttt</li>
</ul>

<span>33</span>
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>tttttt</li>
</ul>
<span>44</span>
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>tttttt</li>
</ul>
<span>55</span>
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>tttttt</li>
</ul>
<span>66</span>
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>tttttt</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<pre>
asdfasdf
asdf
asdf
asfd
a






sdfsdf
sd
fs
dfsd
fsfd
sdf







sdfsdfs
sdf
sfd
</pre>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is that, the right sidebar is position fixed so it took its actual height, but giving the height 100vh or 100% , the right sidebar will took the height of the view port or means browser screen height, which as a result provide the scroll to sidebar.

Hope this will help you for the future for any kind of this situation.